Laptop Keyboard disabled after suspend or sleep Debian 12, How do i fix it?
My Dell laptop has Debian 12, every after I suspend or sleep the laptop the keyboard is disabled when I wake it back. even after using on-screen keyboard to log in, it stays disabled.
I tried changing from Gnome to KDE and the issue persists.
How do i fix it?

Similar issue on Ubuntu, answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/916465/ubuntu-17-04-keyboard-not-responding-after-suspend doesn't fix entire issue. See also https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=150959
